# Book about Tantric Sex Written by an Australian Couple that uses the terms 'Lingam' and 'Yoni'

Tags: identification-request

I am searching for a book about tantric sex for couples written by an Australian couple.  I read the book in northeast USA in english language around 2006.  I think I bought it in a book store at the time, though it could have been new or used.  But it didn't seem like a very old book.  I believe the couple that wrote the book offered some in person counseling as well but I'm not 100% sure about that.

The thing I remember the most was how they called the penis 'lingam' and the vagina 'yoni'.  The book focused more on bonding as a couple as opposed to focusing on yourself. So any books with 'for men' or 'for women' in the title won't fit the bill.  I vaguely remember the cover being yellowish or orangish, but I'm really not that certain and that could of course change in different prints.

I found "The Heart of Tantric Sex: A Unique Guide to Love and Sexual Fulfillment" by Diana Richardson, which seems close, but I don't see any mention of Lingam or Yoni in the sample text online, and it says Diana is from Europe not Australia.

I would love (pun intended) to find this book, and any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Sadly, the work being asked about does not seem to fall in the realm of literature within the scope defined in the [help center](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help); it would therefore be off-topic for our site, which focuses on imaginative and/or historically significant works. You might want to try [Quora](http://quora.com). Good luck!

Comment: Well since I'm not sure enough, and looks like it might be off topic here anyway, I'll just leave it as a comment. I think [Tantric Yoga: The Royal Path to Raising Kundalini Power](https://www.amazon.com/Tantric-Yoga-Royal-Raising-Kundalini-ebook/dp/B007X6M05M) might be the book you read, it's explicitly mentions the terms you remember, and written by a couple who are not from Australia, but I read a bit and they did visit Australia at some point and they might also have suggested personal help.

Comment: Also, while the newer versions are blue, [this one](https://indiaclub.com/products/4068-tantric-yoga-the-royal-path-to-raising-kundalini-power) from 2005 appears to be yellow-ish so might fit.

Comment: @verbose Could you elaborate on why this is off-topic? Seems like a straightforward ID request to me?

Comment: @Skooba a how-to book on tantra doesn't qualify as literature

Comment: @verbose - "*books and writings published on a particular subject*" This seems to fit the description perfectly well

Comment: @verbose I am still confused by what you mean by that? ["We interpret ‘literature’ in a broad sense, including written, spoken and sung works, in all genres, languages and forms: poetry, plays, stories, novels, lyrics, comic books, essays, belles-lettres, and so on.](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This a written work and the subject matter of the work should not preclude it.

Comment: @Skooba I don't agree that any and every written work counts as "Literature" for this group; the examples given (poetry, plays, etc) in the help center clearly allude to *imaginative* literature. Probably a good topic for a meta post, but I'd strongly argue against including (say) newspaper articles or self-help books within our scope.

Comment: @Valorum Where is the quote from? That is *a* definition of literature, but I don't believe that it's the one we (should) use on this site.

Comment: @verbose - OED.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be *[Tantric Secrets for Men: What Every Woman Will Want Her Man to Know about Enhancing Sexual Ecstasy](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tantric-Secrets-Men-Enhancing-Ecstasy-ebook/dp/B071GZNS46?ref_=ast_author_dp)* (2002) by Kerry Riley and Diane Riley?

Warning: NSFW (Nudity)

> [image]

The [bio](https://www.amazon.co.uk/stores/author/B001KJ1Y7S/about) for the author/s state that they're Australian.

> In the 80’s Kerry Riley studied yoga and meditation with Swami
> Satyananda and Masahiro Oki in Japan. He later taught these practices
> along with Chinese medicine, acupuncture and Taoist sexology in the
> East West Foundation in Sydney, Australia. After further extensive
> studies in Japan he introduced ‘Zen Shiatsu’ to Australia. He
> subsequently studied sacred sexuality, tantra and Taoism throughout
> the world with leading teachers in this field, including authors Dr
> Stephen Chang, Charles and Caroline Muir, Larry Collins, and David and
> Ellen Ramsdale. He also studied advanced sexuality at Moore
> University, USA.
>
> Together with his partner, Diane Riley, Kerry was at the forefront of
> the introduction of the philosophy of sacred sexuality to Australia.